# if a quadratic form $Q$ is positive definite then $\big|[Q]-\lambda I_n \big|$ has non-zero alternating sign coefficients

Tags: polynomials, quadratic-forms

Let $Q:\ \mathbb R^n\longrightarrow\mathbb R$ is a positive definite quadratic form and $\mathcal B$ is a basis of $\mathbb R^n$. Then how to show that all coefficients of the characteristic polynomial $\,p(t)=\big|\big[Q\big]_{\mathcal B}-t I_n \big|\, $ are non-zero and alternating in sign ?

My attempt :

Earlier, I showed that every eigenvalue of $ \big[Q\big]_{\mathcal B}$ is positive. Then
$$p(t)\,=\,(-1)^n(t-\lambda_1)\cdots(t-\lambda_n) $$
where $\lambda_i>0$ for all $i$.

When $n=1$, the statement is clearly true. Suppose the statemnent is true for $n$. Consider
\begin{align}
p(t)\,&=\,(-1)^{n+1}(t-\lambda_1)\cdots(t-\lambda_n)(t-\lambda_{n+1})
\\ &=(-1)^{n+1}\Big[(t-\lambda_1)\cdots(t-\lambda_n)t-(t-\lambda_1)\cdots(t-\lambda_n)\lambda_{n+1}\Big].
\end{align}
Suppose
\begin{align}
(t-\lambda_1)\cdots(t-\lambda_n)\,=\,a_0+a_1t+\cdots+a_nt^n
\end{align}
then we have
\begin{align}
p(t)\,=\,(-1)^{n+1}\Big[-\lambda_{n+1}a_0+(a_0-\lambda_{n+1}a_1)t+\cdots+ (a_{n-1}-\lambda_{n+1}a_n) t^n+a_nt^{n+1} \Big].
\end{align}
Assuming without loss of generality that $a_0<0$. By inducing hypothesis, $a_1>0,a_2<0,\cdots$. Hence
\begin{align}
-\lambda_{n+1}a_0\,&>\,0
\\ a_0-\lambda_{n+1}a_1\,&<\,0
\\ &\vdots
\end{align}
Therefore the statement is true for $n+1$. So it is true for every $n$.

Is my proof ok ? Is there others way to solve this problem ? Pleas share your opinion. Thanks.

Comment: You wrote t_i > 0 where I think you mean _i > 0.

Comment: @DanAsimov yeah I just edited that, thanks

Comment: are you familiar with Sylvester's Determinant Criterion for Hermitian (or real symmetric) PD matrices?  What about its generalization for PSD matrices?

Comment: @user8675309 I do know a bout  Sylvester's Determinant Criterion for real matrix